# Prove only 1 solution exists for the following equation $x^2 = y^2 + 71$ where $x, y$ and pos integers

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, singular-solution

Hi I've been stuck on this equation for a while. Pretty sure it has something to do with Pell's equation $x^2 - D y^2 = a$. Not exactly sure.

The question:

(i)Prove that there is only one solution to $x^2 = y^2 + 71$ for positive integers $x$ and $y$.

Then part (ii) which I'm capable of doing if I get (i):

(ii) Hence (and not otherwise) prove that there do not exist three consecutive integer values of $n$ for which $71n + 60$ is a perfect square.

If any of you could help me get (i) that would be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei7j7.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Factor the difference of squares.

Comment: Please use MathJax and fix your title.

Comment: Maybe you mean $x^2-y^2=71?$

Comment: If you use difference of squares, you have (x - y)(x + y) = 71. Since 71 is a prime number, we know either x - y is 71 or x + y is 71. If x - y = 71, then x + y = 1, which means x = 36 and y = -35, which doesn't work because y is negative. however, if x + y = 71 and x - y = 1, then x = 36 and y = 35, which solves the problem - this is the only solution because 71 is prime and only has 71 and 1 as factors.

Comment: Thanks so much :)